# How to import Excel xlsx files into pandas

Tags: pandas

I need to import .XLSX Excel file into pandas it is now unsupported and gives the error

```
XLRDError: Excel xlsx file; not supported
```

I need an alternative for:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("Challenger track/Data Sets/extract-text-1.xlsx", index_col=0)
df.head()
```

Comment: It did answer my question YES, the problem with StackOverflow now is the structure of question may defer from a person to another and the number of results may lead that I won't scroll 500 results for example but thank you so much for referring to that answer

Answer (score 2):

This is the workaround for pandas not supporting xlsx files. Install openpyxl and specify it as the engine when reading an xlsx file as below:

```
xlfile = pd.ExcelFile('sample.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
df = xlfile.parse('sheet_name')
```